# Angular - How to use WebAPI endpoints without hard-coding the endpoint into the httpGet method?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, angular5, angular6

I dont want to do the following:

```
_http.Get('https://someUrl/api/controller').subscribe().....
```

Is there a way around this so as to reduce the hard-coded endpoints?

Comment: You could add the url to your environment files. Would still be a fixed value but only at one central point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep your production and development api endpoint urls (base urls) in the **environments/environment.prod.ts** and  **environments/environment.ts** files.

// dev

```
export const environment = {
   production: false,
   apiUrl: 'dev base url'
};
```

// prod

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'prod base url'
};
```

You can import apiEndpoint in to services or components like this

```
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

constructor() {
    this.apiEndPoint = environment.apiUrl;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

put your api endpoint host into `environment` file and then use

```
http.get(`${environment.host}/variable/part/of/api/url`)
```